# How to Trigger AWS Lambda job when a data is loaded into a certain S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

What is the simplest and most cost effective way to trigger/run an AWS Lambda job whenever a file is put in the AWS S3 Bucket (in a certain path; Even though I know its all object in S3 and not like a File System, but still folder system exists for users' ease)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure an **Amazon S3 Event** on the bucket so that, when a file is added to the given path, it triggers an AWS Lambda function.

See: [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3 - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html)

The Lambda function will be supplied with the Bucket name and Object key that caused the event to trigger.

You can also follow a [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) that demonstrates the concept by uploading an image, which triggers a Lambda function that resizes the image.

Comment: Hi, I used S3 Events and CloudWatch to achieve the same. Now, I have 3 tables to load from 3 different files updated in AWS S3. I'm doing that in one single Lambda.

I do not want to write 3 Lambdas for achieving the same for 3 files. So, just want to know, is there any mechanism by which I can trigger a Lambda, which will run only the part of the file updated using if else? Can some keywords be passed using S3 Events & CloudWatch to check in the if and run that part only?

Comment: Should I write a fresh question for the same?

Comment: When creating an Amazon S3 Event, you specify the path to look in. Any file that is created (or updated or deleted, depending on your config) will trigger ONE specific Lambda function with details of that file provided. What the Lambda code does is totally up to you. The problem with "3 tables to load from 3 different files" is that the Lambda function is triggered when ONE file is created, without knowledge of any other objects in S3. Your Lambda code can look at the filename (Key) and/or the contents of the file, then use an `if` to determine whether to do work, but that is your code.